# How to classify the cell complex (symbol) aabb^(-1)?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I think the Euler characteristic of this symbol is 0 and it's not orientable, so it should be homeomorphic to a sphere with 2 cross-caps, but I'm not sure how to show this. Thank you

Comment: It's actually just a single cross-cap (projective plane.) The Euler characteristic is not 0. There are two edges, two vertices and a single $2$-cell.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any easy way to show this?

Comment: Nevermind, I see now that you can eliminate the bb^(-1)